# Navegação para páginas em subpastas no JSF 2 não funciona

Tags: jsf, jsf-2.2, java

Estou com o seguinte problema: Tenho uma hierarquia de pastas onde separo minhas paginas web do projeto:

```
Web
 |- Acoes
 |   |- usuariosAcoes.xhtml
 |   |- cadastrarAcao.xhtml
 |- usuarios
 |   |- listarUsuarios.xhtml
 |   |- cadastrarUsuario.xhtml
```

Mas quando tento navegar pelo ManagedBean as paginas não carregam, somente atualiza a pagina atual se eu tento acessar uma página que está fora da pasta da pagina atual.

Por exemplo, se estou na página listarUsuarios.xhtml e tento acessar a página cadastrarUsuario.xhtml via ManagedBean tudo funciona:

```
public String acessaCadastro(){ return "cadastrarUsuario"; }
```

porém se estou na página listarUsuarios.xhtml e tento acessar usuariosAcoes.xhtml que está em outra pasta, não acontece nada, somente recarrega a página que já estou:

```
public String acessarAcoesUsuario(){ return "usuariosAcoes"; }
```

tentei assim tembém mas não resolveu:

```
public String acessarAcoesUsuario(){ return "Acoes/usuariosAcoes"; }
```

nem assim:

```
public String acessarAcoesUsuario(){ return "../Acoes/usuariosAcoes"; }
```

e nem assim:

```
public String acessarAcoesUsuario(){ return "Acoes/usuariosAcoes.xhtml"; }
```

ou

```
public String acessarAcoesUsuario(){ return "../Acoes/usuariosAcoes.xhtml"; }
```

Então, como posso resolver esta questão? Lembrando que não uso o faces-config.xml para criar rotas, já que o JSF 2.x já abstrai isso.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creio que isso te ajude

```
public void seuMétodo() {
    ExternalContext externalContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()
                .getExternalContext();
    try {
          externalContext.redirect(externalContext.getRequestContextPath()
                + "/pastaDoArquivo/arquivo.xhtml");
    } catch (IOException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Onde seria chamado o `seuMétodo` no lugar do seu `return "algumaCoisa.xhtml"`.

**Nota**: Eu costumo isolar a lógica de navegação em uma classe específica, tipo um "navigationManagedBean", que irá armazenar todas as minhas chamadas de paginação.

Qualquer dúvida, deixe nos comentários.

Abraço

Comment: Obrigado @Weslley vou testar e lhe dou uma resposta

Comment: Desta forma pra mim funcionou muito bem, obrigado!!! O único porém é que eu perdi o emcapsulamento da URL, pois antes não aparecei o caminho todo na barra de endereços, e agora sempre aparece pra cada página. Mas isso é só estética